# .net core 2.1 IniConfigurationProvider can' read ini-values

Tags: linux, ini, .net-core-2.1

I try the IniConfigurationProvider for read an Ini-File in Linux.

```
string iniFile = "Path\db_replicator.cfg";
if (!File.Exists(iniFile))
    throw new Exception();
IniConfigurationSource iniConfigurationSource = new IniConfigurationSource();
iniConfigurationSource.Path = iniFile;
iniConfigurationSource.Optional = true;
var iniConfigurationProvider = new IniConfigurationProvider(iniConfigurationSource);
iniConfigurationProvider.Load();
string retTestValue = string.Empty;
bool retBooleanTestValue = iniConfigurationProvider.TryGet("Sync:DatabaseDirectory", out retTestValue);
```

The ini-file:

```
[Sync]
DatabaseDirectory=dataDirectory
```

The string `retTestValue` is `null`after the `TryGet("Sync:DatabaseDirectory)` call.

I found an example that shows me a Get-Methode. But I cannot find that in the new .NetCore 2.1 Version; there I only find `TryGet`.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this question trying to get the .NET Core AWS SDK to read the access key id and secret access key from the INI file used by the AWS CLI.  After a bunch more searching, I found that you also need to specify the `FileProvider` for the `IniConfigurationSource`, or it can't figure out where the INI file is, like this:

```
        string userProfilePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
        IniConfigurationSource iniConfig = new IniConfigurationSource { Path = ".aws\\credentials", Optional = true, FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(userProfilePath) };
        IniConfigurationProvider iniProvider = new IniConfigurationProvider(iniConfig);
        iniProvider.Load();
        string accessKey;
        if (iniProvider.TryGet("default:aws_access_key_id", out accessKey))
        {
            string secretKey;
            if (iniProvider.TryGet("default:aws_secret_access_key", out secretKey))
            {
                return new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
            }
        }
        throw new ApplicationException("Unable to find AWS access key id and secret access key in the user's profile .aws\\credentials file!");
```

Comment: You are RIGHT!, The Path prooerty can only specific a relative path, it needs a FileProvider to specific the absolute path. like this:

var configSource = new IniConfigurationSource()
{
    FileProvider=new PhysicalFileProvider(@“C:\config”),
    Path = Path.Combine( "Social", "config.ini")
};
var configProvider = new IniConfigurationProvider(configSource);
configProvider.Load();